Expo Router won't navigate to modal screen when using a top-level group
When attempting to reference a modal screen within a top-level group , Expo Router fails to locate it. I’ve tried various configurations, but the modal remains inaccessible when used within this group.
See https://streamable.com/qk6hww
Reproduction Steps:

Clone the repository here.
Try to open the modal from the header icons on the search and account screens (you'll see the dynamic [id] screen is navigated to instead)

The modal screen should be routed to and presented as a modal.
